# Access local device from Django application

Tags: django, deployment

I have a Django application hosted in the server. Now, I want to implement a feature where people will be able to see the locally connected **Scanner list** and access them directly from the Django-React.js application.

After accessing them, I want to get the scan copy directly into the Frontend.

How to do that?

I found some premium plugins to do that.
But I want something free.

Comment: One way is to create a separate desktop application/ browser extn  which establish a websocket connection and send the scanner details to server( store these in a model) against users.

Comment: That's a great idea.
Besides that, can I get the scanner details to the server from front-end that is developed in React.js?

Comment: Once your models have the scanner details(which are saved by action in the desktop app/ browser extn), you can list these scanners in your webapp. and your server can send instructions to scanner using the websocket connection established b/w the server and the desktop app and vice-versa (  FYI:  every client need to install the desktop app)

Comment: Browser don't  get the hardwares access( scanner, printer, ...) attached to the computer ( due to security reasons)